# Xcode No such file or directory

Tags: xcode, admob

I'm getting an error **"Command Libtool failed with a nonzero exit code"**, but when I investigate the issue, the final error I get is **"fatal error: Can't open file list file (No such directory found)"**. Please look at the image below for a more detailed error.

[image]

The only time I get this error is when I install pods. The only pod file I have is Google Admobs.

I've tried many things like restarting exit code, restarting my laptop, reinstalling pods, deleting derived data, messing with the build settings, and a mixture of everything I've tried. I even tried creating a new project and moving over my entire app but still nothing.

Let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: Maybe you need open the *.xcworkspace file, not *.xcodeproj

Comment: No, I opened the correct file.

Comment: Have you tried a new project with the pod file, but no code of your self? If there is no error, try moving over parts (if possible) of your own code until you get the error back.

Comment: The strangest thing just happened. I created a dummy project to test it out and it worked. So I created another empty project with the app name in a different file location and it didn't work. My guess is that the name of the project is somehow messed up. I'll try again with a different name and slowly move over my first project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @koen for the answer. Creating a new project with a different product name removes the error.

I'm sure if I use the previous product name I'll get the error back but I'm satisfied with this workaround!